# How to enable the default anchor behavior with Bootstrap smooth scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like smooth scrolling as well as links to other pages. And on other pages when click on some of hash links to redirect to that page to that link.

Just like the behavior of the ancor without prevent default(), but with prevent default() if know what i meen.
Any ideas?

This is my function:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Add scrollspy to <body>
      $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   

      // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
      $("#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 a, #totop a").on('click', function(event) {
       // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){

          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

This is my nav

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="<?=base_url();?>#top">Начало</a> </li>
                <li ><a href="<?=base_url();?>#services">Продукти</a></li>
                <li ><a href="<?=base_url('news');?>">Новини</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#aboutus">За нас <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li ><a href="#contacts">Контакти</a></li>
            </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Търси в продукти" name="search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Търсене</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```